# Milky Way was unexplored because it seemed uninhabitable to all other life, shocked when humans inhabit it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been looking for a short story that I read online a few years back. I was told it could be "All the Way Back", but it just doesn't sounds right.

The one I read was the same concept, that Earth is in a void of the universe that all other life thinks is a dead zone but it didn't have the same twist that humans were the race all other alien races fought against.

This particular story, if I remember correctly, was that the Milky Way was unexplored because it checked out as uninhabitable to all other life, so when we breached the Milky Way it was a huge shock to the rest of the universe.

Comment: Do you know what you read this? Was it new then? What language was it in?

Comment: It was a part of a list of short story ideas I saw on Imgur, I think. It was easily a 15 minute read that felt like I had just read the CliffsNotes of a very good book.

Comment: You can [edit] information into your question!

Comment: And for what it's worth we prefer titles to be descriptive of the work, here you're losing a lot of information by keeping it as you have done so. I will not roll it back though if this is what you want to keep.

Comment: If it'll help get an answer you can do whatever you want

Comment: This is almost certainly [All The Way Back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/short-story-humans-as-the-bad-guys/52240#52240)...

Comment: So if that is the case, do any of Shaara's novels or short stories continue the story?

Comment: @LeglessPooch - Just a one-off, I believe

Comment: The question reminds me of a story but I cannot find it. If it is the same one, humans had previously been space conquers and the void is caused by all their outposts/colonies having been destroyed when the other races rose against them.  At one time the humans had genetically modified a rebel race to be born with no left arm which reminded the human character of Caesar's punishments in Gaul.  Does this ring any bells?

Comment: @AlanT that is 100% "All the Way Back". I bought it on Amazon for $1 and read it. Good read, really short though. After I read it though it is not the same story I read on Imgur all those years ago. The one I read was the same concept but it had no end, it was more of a CliffsNotes that read like an open ended idea for a story.

Comment: @LeglessPooch Yep. Just looked at the story in the link above and it is the one I remember it's just that I don't/didn't recognise the author's name. Thanks