# Aliens united to destroy a violent race, but the twist is that it’s humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, first-contact

I'm looking for a sci-fi short story where a crew from Earth makes first contact with an alien. The alien tells them about how all the alien races united to destroy an extremely violent/belligerent species that threatened everyone. They defeated and exterminated the species, but a few got away.

At the end, we learn this ancient enemy was humanity. And then Earth gets destroyed.

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52020/a-short-story-about-finding-an-inhabitable-planet-and-meeting-aliens and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/story-about-human-space-explorers-who-run-into-alien-telepath-space-crew and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/short-story-humans-as-the-bad-guys/52240#52240

Comment: Probably still a duplicate, but Earth does not in fact get destroyed. The aliens have no clue where we are.